# how to force python output saved as an excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I have a python script running on a server. as the result, it creates an excel workbook using the openpyxl library, and I write it on the disk with the help of tempfile library in a tempfile on the servers disk.
But at this point, I want to make the client's browser download the workbook too. what should I do?

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:# and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            output = gen_file(file)
            #gen_file makes a new excel workbook from the uploaded file
            return output
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

and this is the last part of my gen_file function

```
    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".xlsx",dir=".",delete=False) as tmp:
        output_workbook.save(tmp)
        return tmp.name
```

Comment: This is very unclear what you need and what you have. For downloading a file from a server, there are tons of different ways. Are you running a webserver like nginx or apache? What are your clients? If you want to serve the file through a web page, you are going to need a webserver in order to do that.

Comment: it's a simple program. currently it uses flask on my own computer on port 5000. the client is firefox. It will go on a server and the client will be different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using flask, your options are either serving the file directly from your flask app, or using a load balancer like `nginx` and put your files inside the `nginx`'s public directory.

For the first option, you could use something like below:

```py
from flask import Response

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:# and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            output = gen_file(file)
            #gen_file makes a new excel workbook from the uploaded file
            file_content = open(output, 'r').read()
            return Response(
                file_content,
                mimetype="text",
                headers={"Content-disposition":
                    f"attachment; filename=anything.csv"})
```

`<file_content>` can be anything. you can read your file content using python's builtin functions such as `open`.

Comment: based upon the parts of my code added above, how can I change your code to make the browser download my tempfile?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I cannot check it yet, I'll try it as soon as I have access to the code again, in two days. But there is already a question here: when I had that 'f' before the '"attachment;..." it gave me syntax error. what does it do?

Comment: That's a `f-string` introduced in python 3. If you are using python 2, remove that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to change the return value of my gen_file function so it returns the file name. Everything works as it should be, now.
I updated the last part of my gen_file function so others can have the working code.